# char_filter not set propoerly

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I am setting up custom char_filter in elastic search django but I am unable to replace it

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer

remove_leading_and_symbol_char_filter = char_filter(
'remove_leading_and_symbol', 'pattern_replace',
pattern="&",
replacement="")

html_strip = analyzer('html_strip',
tokenizer="standard",
filter=["standard", "lowercase"],
char_filter=["html_strip", remove_leading_and_symbol_char_filter]
)
```

When I am querying my indexes with "and" instead of "&" it does not throw any result.

Comment: can you provide the o/p of _setting APIhttps://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html which will show whether your char filter is properly set or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine now, I have added that analyzer to my target field that I want to analyze , previously I was trying to bind that analyzer to all fields and that didn't work.

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index, fields
from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer, tokenizer, char_filter, token_filter
from django_app.models import ex_model

posts = Index('index_name')

remove_leading_and_symbol_char_filter = char_filter(
'remove_leading_and_symbol', 'mapping',
mappings=[ "&=> and "])

html_strip = analyzer('html_strip',
tokenizer="standard",
filter=["standard", "lowercase"],
char_filter=["html_strip", remove_leading_and_symbol_char_filter]
)

posts.analyzer(html_strip)
@posts.doc_type
class ExampleDocument(DocType):

    target_field = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
    )
    class Meta:
        model = ex_model
        field = [
        'field_1',
        'field_2'
        ]
```

Hope this will help someone